# JavaScript - How can I add functions from different files to a class?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm quite new to OOP Javascript and I'm not sure how to accomplish the following:

I have a class in my **index.js** but since I don't want  to put a bunch of code in my index file I thought it would be more organized to separate in different files (like putting together similar functions in the same file).

Each function depends on two constants, `key` and `secret`, I use those paramaters **inside** of each function. I can easily solve this by doing:

```
const Person function(key, secret) {
  this.functionOne = (key, secret, functionParameter) {};
}
```

But I dont want to ask for `key` and `secret` (they are constants, like an api key and secret) every time I want to use `functionOne`. What I want is, to have each function (from different files) get the value from `key` and `secret`somehow without having to put it manually every time I use a function from `Person`. Like this:

**index.js**

```
const Person function(key, secret) {
  this.personAction= (key, secret, thing) {};
}
```

**myFunctions.js**

```
personAction function(thing) {
  // do something with key and secret
}
```

and then be able to do this

```
const person1 = new Person('my_key123', 'my_secret123');
person.personAction('thing');
```

The only way I could think of was by putting all the similar functions into its own class, then in my main class (`Person`), return an object initializing every class with my functions, like this:

```
// index.js
const Person function(key, secret) {
  return {
    myFunctions: new MyFunctions(key, secret),
    otherFunctions: new OtherFunctions(key, secret)
  }
}

// myFunctions.js
const MyFunctions function(key, secret) {
  this.something= (thing) => {// do something with my key and secret}
}
```

By doing that I can actually do this:

```
const person1 = new Person('my_key', 'my_secret');
person1.myFunctions.something('hello')
```

But this doesn't feel like the right way to do it, is there another way to do this?

***P.S: I'm sorry if I didn't explain what I'm trying to do very well, it was hard to explain, if I wasn't clear enough let me know.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bend over backwards with weird constructions of your own. This is perfectly solved in standard OOP:

```
function Person(key, secret) {
    this.key = key;
    this.secret = secret;
}

Person.prototype.functionOne = function (functionParameter) {
    console.log(this.key, this.secret, functionParameter);
};

var person1 = new Person('my_key', 'my_secret');
person1.functionOne('hello')
```

Since prototype functions are attached one by one to the `prototype` property, you can easily keep those functions in a different file and "put the class together" afterwards. However, I have no idea why you'd want to do this. Typically you'll want to keep one class definition self-contained within one file, otherwise you'll have a hard time tracking all its components and seeing "the big picture" of what your class actually does. The only exception to that would be "mixins" which can be reused between different classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
const Person  = function(key, secret) {
  this.key = key;
  this.secret = secret;
  this.personAction= function(thing) {
    //access this.key and this.secret
  };
};
```

For putting the method in a separate file, try this

```
const Person  = function(key, secret) {
  this.key = key;
  this.secret = secret;
};

Person.prototype.personAction= function(thing) {
    //access this.key and this.secret
};
```

Comment: The first sample arguably doesn't need `this` at all, you could just use the closed-over `key` and `secret` directly.

Comment: In OP's sample, he is doing `myFunctions: new MyFunctions`, so I guess we would need `this`. But in this case, both `key` and `secret` becomes public

Comment: @deceze I assumed that there may be other functions which could spill over files so added `key` and `secret` as properties of `Person`.